# React router dom routing redirect

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

I have a website created with ReactJS and React Router Dom. I use `createBrowserRouter` for routing pages. However, when I refresh any page, I encounter a 404 error ("page not found"). This issue arises when I deploy the project on server platforms like Domain.com. Does anyone have a solution?

I've tried using `createHashRouter`, but I dislike the "#" in the URL.

Comment: This is a server/hosting issue, the basic gist being that the server or hosting service should be configured to return the root index.html file for all page requests into your app. Each server/hosting environment is different and may require vastly different setups/configurations. Where are you deploying your app? See CRA's [deployment docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/) to get a sense for the types of setups/configurations are necessary. In the meantime, if you still need help  then please [edit] the post to include more complete details.